# Boundedness indices in Voevodsky's smash nilpotence conjecture in family

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, motives, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Voevodsky introduced the following notion : an algebraic cycle $Z$ in $X$ is *smash nilpotent* if there exist $N>0$ such that $Z^N$ is rationally equivalent to $0$ in $X^N$.

Voevodsky conjectured that a cycle on $X$ is numerically equivalent to $0$ if and only if it is smash nilpotent.

I was wondering if we expect some sort of boundedness for the indices $N$ when $Z$ vary in family. Namely, let:
$$ f : X \longrightarrow B$$
be a smooth projective morphism with $B$ smooth and quasi projective over $k$. Let $Z$ be a cycle in $X$ such that $Z_b$ is numerically equivalent to $0$ for all closed points $b \in B$. By Voevodsky's conjecture, for all closed points $b \in B$, there exists $N_b>0$ such that $Z^{N_b}$ is rationally equivalent to $0$ in $X^{N_b}$. Up to shrinking $B$, do we expect that the set of indices $N_b, b \in B$ is bounded? If not, are there some reasonable extra assumptions on $Z$ or $X$ that would grant this?

Comment: When you write "for all $b\in B$", do you mean for every point of the scheme (including the generic point, thus answering your own question), or do you mean for every $k$-valued point of $B$?  If $k$ is $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, there are some pretty strange behaviors, cf. results of Bogomolov and Bogomolov-Tschinkel on zero-cycles on K3 surfaces over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Comment: Indeed, I meant closed points. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If $Z_b$ is *algebraically* equivalent to zero for all points $b$ (not just closed ones), then yes. Hint: Voevodsky's argument works over any field. Since we don't know anything better about Voevodsky's conjecture I would imagine that's the best we can do right now, but please prove me wrong.

Comment: This should certainly be true. Being numerically equivalent to $0$ is conjecturally the same as being homologically equivalent to $0$, so the condition would also hold for the generic point of $B$. The integer obtained by applying the nilpotence conjecture to the generic (or geometric generic) point of $B$ will work for all closed points since specialisation preserves rational equivalence.

Comment: @Naf : very interesting. Could you make a detailed answer out of your comment? I am ready to admit the standard conjectures to get a positive answer to this question.

Comment: I understood a different question, which is why I asked the OP to clarify: “without assuming the conjecture, is there an a priori bound just for closed points (thus giving inductive evidence for the conjecture)?”  Both Johan and I observed that such a bound follows if you assume the conjecture for generic points.

Comment: @JasonStarr If $k$ is uncountable, then the question has a positive answer by the usual tricks? Do you agree?

Comment: @Johan Yes, I agree.  However, results about “triviality” of cycles sometimes hold over finite fields by special arguments, cf. Bogomolov’s conjecture on $\text{CH}_0$ of K3 surfaces.

Comment: @Johan : may I ask what are *the usual tricks*?

Comment: Some of the "usual tricks" are the "limit theorems" in EGA IV_3, Sections 8, 11, 17, etc.

Comment: @Libli Sorry, yes, what Jason said. Another way to say it: $f$, $X$, $B$, $Z$ can be defined over $k_0$ countable subfield of $k$ giving $Z_0 \subset X_0 \to B_0$ over $k_0$. Then you can use the assumption for suitable $b \in B_0(k)$ mapping to the generic point of $B_0$ to sort of argue as in Jason's very first comment. So, Jason was right from the start that the interesting case is when $k$ is "small".